# Aggregation and Compostion relationship in class diagram

Tags: class, diagram

i want to know that when there is an aggregation or composition relation between the two classes,can both classes share attributes of each other?

if there is a class called account which has a composition relation with class customer
so is class account can access the variables of class customer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Class can access the non-private fields of related classes, may it be aggregation or composition.

In the below example, class A & B holds a composition relationship and A can access fields and methods of B. But this depends on the visibility of the variable and method.

```
class A {
String test;
B b;
void printB(){
b.getTest();}
}

class B {
private String test;
public String getTest(){
return test;
}
}
```

Comment: I disagree. Aggregation is not about accessibility, it's an association with an additional ownership trait. Composition is a stronger form of aggregation, where the "owned" class has an association with the owning class only, and as such may be invisible to other classes.

Comment: Who told it is related to accessibility? Did you read the question? The question was if there is a relationship between two classes, whether it is possible to access certain attributes of the related classes and yes it is possible but depends on some conditions.

Comment: Sharing attributes sound like accessibility to me.

Comment: Probably, person is new to OOP and might be learning his basics on creating these relationship with the classes.

Comment: Maybe, anyways, my point was that aggregation and composition as concepts are unrelated to sharing attributes. As you say, they may or may not, but the answer to OP's question is not Yes, IMO.

Comment: You are not understanding the question. The question was not about whether these relationship are related to sharing variables or accessing variables. The question was if there is a relationship, then is it possible to access variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is not importent if two classes are connected with relationship or not. Attributes are accessible to any element if visibility of attribute is set to public (or package if elemenents reside in the same package). For example you can access public attribute of class in activity action which pin type is class with public attributes etc.